# Cannot get an html hidden field value from a viewbag value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to get a count of the records returned in an ajax call so I can display a proper message.

My datatype must be "html", so I can't check any json values to see if any records are returned.

However, I do extract the count in a ViewBag variable in a controller which in turn is hidden in an html hidden variable.

When I go and check for the value in the JS, it is an empty string.

I have verified that the Viewbag controller property has a value of 0 and the assignment of the hidden html variable is 0 from the Viewbag.

When I check for the value in the ajax success method, it is **an empty string instead of a "0".**

I even tried assigning a var value to retrieve from the jquery *projCnt* variable.

What am I missing here???

### Controller

```
ViewBag.projectCount = customer.Projects.Count.ToString();
            return View(customer);
```

Value in ViewBag.projectCount = "0"

### HTML

```
<div>
  @Html.Hidden("projCnt", (string)ViewBag.projectCount)
</div>
```

Value in projCnt = "0"

### JS

```
if ($('#projCnt').val() == "0")
```

Value in projCnt = ""

[image]

### EDIT

Too many chars in literal
[image]
[image]

Comment: You image is difficult to read - you claim the html is `Value in projCnt = "0"` but what you have shown appears to be `<input id="projCnt" value="" ..>`?

Comment: I take it that `@Html.Hidden("projCnt", (string)ViewBag.projectCount)` is in the partial view your returning in the ajax call, and not in the main page?

Comment: try to print @ViewBag.project Count.ToString() just below the body tag

Comment: Correct... It only works if I hard code the value in the html page like so: @Html.Hidden("projCnt", "0")
If I include the actual variable like this: @Html.Hidden("projCnt", (string)ViewBag.projectCount) and check the value during debugging, I get the answer "Too many characters in character literal".

Comment: After you check out my edit, please inform me why I am getting that error. If I can resolve that, it will work fine... Thanks in advance...

Comment: because you're using single quotes ( ' ) for more than one char

Comment: Yes, I did, but get the msg: "Cannot perform binding on a null reference". I have the following code set as you said: <body>ViewBag.projectcount.ToString(); In the GET I'm setting that ViewBag property to "0" & retrieving it out of the POST. Then setting it in the HTML (as described in previous posts); then checking the value in the html.

Comment: If solving the single quote issue will resolve this issue, what would be the exact syntax I would need to pass the value along as?

Comment: The question is how can I place double quotes around the projectCount variable when I'm assigning it to the hidden html field. @Html.Hidden("projCnt", (string)ViewBag.projectCount)? What would be the syntax I can use?

Comment: Bottom line is simply to fix the error "Too many characters in character literal". This needs to be fixed when assigning the ViewBag variable to the Html field. As my screen suggests, the ViewBag.projectcount property has a value of "0". I simply need to assign this to the html variable, but cannot because of that error. After the assignment, in the Immediate Window I type the following and still get the same error: ?document.getElementById('projCnt'). Instead of single quotes, I try double quotes, and get "The name 'document' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: "Cannot perform binding on a null reference " , This error indicates ViewBag.projectCount is null when you try to print it...  Now I understand that you're trying debbuging Javascript in VS Immediate Window. Visual studio is not prepared to do that, for debbug javascript I think it's better use Ch or FF .

Comment: After I set the ViewBag property in the GET to 0, I wasn't getting the "Cannot perform binding on a null reference". this obviously messed up the value of the property when assigned to the html variable. It now works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Finally!! That's Great!